# How Recursion is taking place in given lines of code?

Tags: c, function, recursion, data-structures

***Can anyone please tell how this lines of code works?***

In this given code how the function is getting executed?
That is tower(n-1, sourcePole, auxiliaryPole,destinationPole); in this part how values are being arranged thereby producing the mentioned output.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-functions/

```
#include<stdio.h>
 
// Assuming n-th disk is bottom disk (count down)
void tower(int n, char sourcePole, char destinationPole, char auxiliaryPole)
{
   // Base case (termination condition)
   if(0 == n)
     return;
 
   // Move first n-1 disks from source pole
   // to auxiliary pole using destination as
   // temporary pole
   tower(n-1, sourcePole, auxiliaryPole,
      destinationPole);
 
    // Move the remaining disk from source
   // pole to destination pole
   printf("Move the disk %d from %c to %c\n",
    n,sourcePole, destinationPole);
 
   // Move the n-1 disks from auxiliary (now source)
   // pole to destination pole using source pole as
   // temporary (auxiliary) pole
   tower(n-1, auxiliaryPole, destinationPole,
     sourcePole);
}
 
int main()
{
   tower(3, 'S', 'D', 'A');
    
   return 0;
}
```

**The output is**

```
Move the disk 1 from S to D
Move the disk 2 from S to A
Move the disk 1 from D to A
Move the disk 3 from S to D
Move the disk 1 from A to S
Move the disk 2 from A to D
Move the disk 1 from S to D
```

Comment: Recursion takes place when a function calls itself.  Therefore, the recursion happens in 2 places in the given code when `tower()` calls `tower()` again.  That's how recursion works.  The algorithm is farily transparent.  If you have trouble seeing it in your head, grab a pencil and execute the instructions by hand.

Comment: okay then how after calling procedure the printf() function produces this output?

Comment: Because the function returns, and the printf is then emitted.  The trick is the guard at the top `if( n==0)` whcih prevents it from recursing forever.

Comment: Okay,What are the prerequesites that needed to understand this code?

Comment: Logic and a basic understanding of C syntax.  What are the parameters when the first call is made?  What is `n`?  What happens next?  The comments actually explain exactly what's happening.

Answer (score -1):

Try to Understand from the from the image:

[image]

Comment: Add images as images instead of links pls. Answer looks to me as it might be helpful but it seems  it got downvoted because of that single link no one even clicked at. Also some text explanation to the image would be better.